# mod_vhsot_alias vs mod_vhost_hash_alias

Tags: subdomain, apache-2.2

I am running Ubuntu Maverick + Apache2.2 and I did some reading up on using mod_vhost_alias to serve/create subdomains on the fly.

But, when I try installing it through apt, all I can find is mod_vhost_hash_alias.

Is this the same thing?
Where is all the documentation for it?

The following query of the apache website returns no useful information
http://www.google.com/search?&q=mod_vhost_hash_alias+site:apache.org

Thanks

Comment: mod_vhost_hash_alias in an out of tree module for Apache's HTTPD server. It's used to host a really massive / large amount of virtual host on a server. With own Apache mod_vhost_alias, you will find many (most) sites on a common subdirectory: it will make it difficult to have a simple policy to distribute to file-servers: some will have more sites to hold. With mod_vhost_*hash*_alias, by hashing the hostname, web sites will be equally/uniformly distributed on the filesystem. It's used by http://vhffs.org/doc:installationguide:web-service, more https://gitorious.org/mod-vhost-hash-alias#more

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your distribution, but, if it's Debian or Ubuntu, it's included in the default Apache package.

Just `a2enmod vhost_alias` and restart Apache.